# Hugo Academic Group not rendering theme

Tags: r, rstudio, hugo, blogdown

I have been having trouble rendering the Hugo theme academic group - [Linked here](https://github.com/biaslab/hugo-academic-group). This is a wonderful modification to the academic package for lab groups. I have been in contact with the developers who noted that the theme using the example works fine on their end (not rendered through RStudio) which makes me think it's how RStudio is rendering the theme. The standard academic theme renders fine.

The template only produces a non-formatted website (below). This occurs in the local viewer, when run through the "build site" option, and when run in a browser. When this theme is run in a different program it renders correctly, so appears to be an RStudio issue.

**Reproducible**

*Approach 1:*
Start new Rstudio blogdown website (need blogdown installed):  Start the project using the hugo theme "biaslab/hugo-academic-group" then run `blogdown::serve_site()`.

This produces the following error `Error: Error building site: failed to render pages: render of "page" failed: execute of template failed: template: post/single.html:19:19: executing "post/single.html" at <partial "authors" .Params.authors>: error calling partial`. RStudio produces a non-formatted website.

[image: ]](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)

*Approach 2:*
As recommended by the theme developer's readme on [GitHub](https://github.com/biaslab/hugo-academic-group), I started a new website using the academic theme (or any theme/ blank theme will do)

Download the academic-group-theme from Github into the `themes` folder, and then copy all the contents of the  `exampleSite`  folder to the `root` of your website, overwriting the content that's there.

When run this way, there is no longer an error, however, the website still renders without formatting (Same as above). The formatting issue continues when running in browser and not in the RStudio local viewer.